# rvmrc specifies 1.9.3 but bundle install --deployment uses 1.9.1? why so?

Tags: deployment, rvm, capistrano, bundler

My rails app (myapp) has a .rvmrc containing

```
# cat .rvmrc
rvm --create use ruby-1.9.3-p0@myapp
```

When I deploy my app using capistrano in production (which works fine)...

```
#cat deploy.rb
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'rvm/capistrano'
...

#cap deploy
```

I noticed bundle install --deployment installs the gems in the *shared/bundle* directory which is fine.

```
* executing "cd /usr/local/mycompany/myapp/releases/20130523003402 &&
bundle install --gemfile /usr/local/mycompany/myapp/releases/20130523003402/Gemfile
               --path /usr/local/mycompany/myapp/shared/bundle
               --deployment 
               --quiet 
               --without development test"
```

Im just curious why the ruby version that bundle uses is 1.9.1. Shouldn't it pick up 1.9.3 as specified in my .rvmrc?

```
/usr/local/mycompany/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1.9.1` is ruby compatibility level, all `1.9..*` rubies are supposed to be compatible so theoretically it should be safe to use gems from ruby `1.9.2` in ruby `1.9.3`, in practice there is more factors then just ruby version - but being careful you could share gems between ruby versions.

Comment: That's great to know!  Is there somewhere the 'ruby compatibility level' is documented?  What is it for 2.0.0 for example?

Comment: check ABI version here http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ReleaseEngineering